# How to format a website to display in columns in search engines and seo?

Tags: seo, search-engine, google-search

http://bit.ly/wYoluw  [Example: Stack Overflow in Search Engine]

Does Google and other search engines do this automatically or is there a specific way to do this?

If there is a way to force a site to display in this column formatting, does it change if using a Wordpress website or something else?

If not, how do search engines decide which site to show in this way? What are the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

They are called sitelinks.

Google will decide on their own if you should have sitelinks and when it wants to display them.

Generally only the top results get them and they relate to important pages on your website.